# mysql max working from phpmyadmin but give me a wrong value from php script?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i didn't find anywhere a solution for my problem.
I am trying to get the max value from mysql (suppose to be 9) table but i get a wrong number (4) in the result.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once(db_connect.php);
$id_num = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(cart_id) FROM user_cart");
echo $id_num;
?>
```

I saw that someone posted here a similar problem but it did not answered my problem.

Comment: you need to use mysql_result() for fetch the result

Comment: Try this: SELECT '9';

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(cart_id) FROM user_cart");
echo mysql_result($query, 0);
```

Still, you shouldn't use mysql_query or mysql_result anymore, they are depracated. Use mysqli instead